# Git view checkin/commit history to a branch

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am new to Git so asking some basic questions related to it.
Earlier I have used clearcase and svn.

For instance in Subversion when we make some file changes and we checkin/commit them then a log of the same gets created as seen in the link "https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html". So a log history of various checkins/commits and files checked in during each commit is maintained by Subversion.

Does Git also maintains such history of all checkins to a branch and files changed/added/deleted during each check in?
How to see this info(various checkin/commits to a branch and files effected in each commit) in Git extension/browser or through commands?

In other words: In Git in any branch suppose today I checkin/commit some file changes. Then after few days I again make some more changes/add/delete some files and checkin  them.
Now after some more days I want to see all commits to a branch and what all files I have changed/checked in during each check in/commit.
How can I see all checkin related info in Git extension/browser or through commands?

Answer (score 2):

> Does GIT also maintains such history of all checkins to a branch and files changed/added/deleted during each check in?

No: Git's model is entirely different.

> In other words: In GIT in any branch suppose today I checkin/commit some file changes.

Git does not store *changes*.  Git stores *commits*.  Each commit represents a complete snapshot of *every file*, whole and intact, with the contents that each such file had at the time you made the commit.

More precisely, a commit is an object—this is a Git term, but we can use it generically here too—identified by a unique hash ID such as `5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7` (this is the hash ID of a commit in the Git repository for Git) that:

- contains some metadata, such as the name of the person making the commit, an email address, and a timestamp;
- contains the hash ID of its immediate predecessor commit(s)—usually just one such;
- contains a log message, which you supply; and
- contains the hash ID of a Git object representing the snapshot.

The extra levels of indirection (commits contain hash IDs of trees that contain hash IDs of blobs that contain the files' contents) allows Git to re-use unmodified files across multiple commits.  Every Git object is 100% read-only, so that once committed, all the files' contents are saved for all time (or at least, until the commit itself is removed, which is quite tricky).

Git will *present* commits *to* you as changes, but to do that, `git log` starts at the *last* commit, identified by its hash ID, which you must somehow provide.  (You can do it by raw hash ID, but that's ugly.  We'll come back to this in a moment.)  That's the *last* commit because Git now works *backwards*, using the predecessor hash ID stored in that commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- start here at H
```

Commit `H` is a full snapshot of all files.  So is commit `G`, `H`'s predecessor.  Git extracts the two commits, compares them, and prints out the *difference* between them, to show you what happened in `H`.

Now that Git has shown `H`, it can move back to `G`.  To show what happened in `G`, Git extracts its predecessor `F`, extracts `G`, compares them, and prints out the *difference*.

The `git log` command is the one that does this backwards-walking.  It shows the log message and, with `-p`, does the extract-and-diff as well.

The `git show` command, presented with a hash ID, prints the log message and does one backwards-walk-step-and-diff and then stops.

The hash IDs here are, of course, horrific and totally unsuited to normal human use.  Unlike SVN revision numbers, there is no relationship between any two back-to-back commit hash IDs.  You're not expected to memorize them.  Instead, Git offers you two main ways to have *Git* remember them for you:

- Tag names store a hash ID, more or less permanently.  Given a commit that's a final release, you might want to tag it as such.  No one will ever change which commit is release `v2.20.0`, so you can tag `5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7` with the name `v2.20.0` and never have to remember the big ugly hash ID again.
- Branch *names*—which we might want to distinguish from *branches*, although this gets a bit tricky—also store a hash ID.  A key difference from a tag, though, is that when you are on a branch and make a *new* commit, Git *automatically updates the branch name to store the new commit's new hash ID.*

Let's look at that earlier drawing again, and add a branch name, `master`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master (HEAD)
```

The name `master` has the word `HEAD` attached to it.  This means it's our *current branch*.

Let's go ahead and make a *new* commit now (with the usual mucking about with modifying files and `git add` and so on).  Git collects our log message, freezes all the files' contents forever, makes a tree object to remember them, and makes a commit object to store the metadata like the hash ID of commit `H`, the hash ID of the new tree, the log message we entered, and so on.  This new commit object gets some new big ugly hash ID, which we'll call `I` instead of guessing at it.  The *parent* for `I` will be `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I
```

As the *last* step of our `git commit`, Git now writes the actual hash ID of `I` into the name `master`, where `HEAD` is attached:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

So now, if we ask Git to show us `master`, Git will extract `I`, show `I`'s log message, extract `H`, compare that to the extracted `I`, and show us the diff from `H` to `I`—all without us having to type in any hash IDs.

Note that if we attach a *new* branch name `develop` to `H` before committing, and make that our `HEAD`, the new commit `I` goes on the new branch instead:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

The commit happened in *precisely the same way*.  The hash ID may even be exactly the same (though this requires that we make the commit at the exact same second, as hash IDs encode the time-stamps inside the commits).  What changed is *which branch name Git wrote the new hash ID into.*

This is what Git branches are about: they're movable pointers, pointing to the commits.  It's the *commits* that matter.  The branch names are just easy ways to obtain commit hash IDs, that automatically move as we work.

Each commit is a full snapshot, and it's the hash IDs that matter.  The names are just there to locate the hash IDs.  Most of the rest of Git's apparent-weirdness, when you come from SVN or Clearcase, is due to these two facts.  (Most of the rest is due to Git's *index*, which I won't cover here.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for 
git log -p. shows you the difference in the files you changed.
Plus there are many other options of git log that can help you narrow down to specifically what you are looking for. This is the reference  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History